# iframe security postmessage high jacking

Tags: javascript, iframe

if a parent from URL X loads an iframe to URL Y.. the parent can use [Window/postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to talk to the child frame.

However, if the parent also loads a 3rd party js snippet - eg google analytics... what is to stop the 3rd party injecting javascript into the parent and then targetting the aforementioned iframe to send content via the postmessage API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely nothing.

If a webpage loads third-party JS then it is giving that JS full access to the execution environment of the page, including the ability to send cross-origin messages marked as originating from that page.

Don't load untrusted third-party JS.